# How to Share Sessions Between Two Web Applications in Websphere

Tags: session, web-applications, jakarta-ee, websphere

Is there any way to share Sessions between two web applications installed on Same Websphere Instance. My Websphere Version is 6.1.

Thanks and Regards,

Sunny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you need this you can use the following WebSphere extension to achieve this.

Do notice that both these web apps are part of the same Enterprise Application.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tprs_sharing_data.html

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Yes they are on the Same Websphere Instance

Comment: @Sannisetty Pavan - Read Manglu's answer more carefully. It is not sufficient that they run in the same server instance, the web applications must be packaged and deployed in the same enterprise application (ear).